# jquery change background-image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function slideSwitch() {
    $("#bgvid").css("background-image", "url(/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg)");
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

[image]

[image]

It should say my website name in the url path there so I add it to the jquery:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    $("#bgvid").css("background-image", "url(the_vegan_repository/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg)");
}
```

and get:

> jquery.js:6685 GET
>   http://localhost:8888/the_vegan_repository/the_vegan_repository/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg
>   404 (Not Found)

How do I make it find my resource by pointing it to `the_vegan_repository/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg`?

Comment: `url(/the_vegan_repository/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    $("#bgvid").css("background-image", "url('/the_vegan_repository/assets/images/home_page/auckland.jpg')");
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```